# Get Computed Height - Javascript - Not jQuery

Tags: javascript, height

I have two divs side by side set to height auto. I want them to have equal height, so i combined them as members of an array.

I recurse through the array and set the not-tallest ones to the height of the tallest. Problem is everything i have tried to get the COMPUTED height has resulted in the incorrect value.

I have tried the following:

```
(els[x].currentStyle) ? h=els[x].currentStyle.height : h=window.getComputedStyle(els[x],null).height;

h =  el.clientHeight || el.offsetHeight || el.scrollHeight;
```

Both of these are yielding 640 px'ish while the computed is 751.8 in my particular showing.

Is there possbily a constant I can use to get the correct height. Like maybe the number im getting would be on a standard size screen (like 960 pixels high or such) then multiple that by the window size?

Comment: How about `outerHeight` ?

Comment: How about `getBoundingClientRect()`?

Comment: Is there Padding and/or borders?

Comment: outerHeight is undefined. No padding or borders present. I tried using a screen height of 980 and that is actually yielding something close. im betting the browsers are using some kind of constant THEN resizing for screen size. So the numbers im getting are based on that.

Comment: I didnt try that method yet Joe, seems like itll take a minute for me to figure out the syntax.

Comment: Well I wasnt able to get the computed height even with getBoundingClientRect. I suspect that firebug installation is causing some of the headache since it causes resizing. I did however come up iwth a reasonable solution: take the difference of each member and the tallest member and add that difference as paddingBottom. Gives a rather clean result.

Answer (score 10):

I have had a lot of good use of this little function I came up with

```
function getH(id)
{
    return document.getElementById(id).offsetHeight;
}
// I have a styles.js file where this function feels right at home. Access this function from anywhere.
```

This will return the height of any given elements given to the function (by it's ID). So now we'r 1/3 of the way.

Then use the Math.max() function to get the height of the largest element.

```
var maxH = Math.max(getH("ID1"),getH("ID2"));
```

This is 2/3 of the way, YAY - Now set the elements height to be the same.

```
var x = document.getElementById("ID1");
var y = document.getElementById("ID2");

x.style.height = maxH +"px";
y.style.height = maxH +"px";  //Remember the +"px" has to be added as a string, thats the reason for the "".
```

DONE!! - Now put it all together

I would imagine something like this

```
function setElementHeight()
{
    var maxH = Math.max(getH("ID1"),getH("ID2"));
    var x = document.getElementById("ID1");
    var y = doc...("ID2");
    x.style.height = maxH +"px";
    y.style.height = maxH +"px";
}
// Don't forget to include the first function in you'r .js file
```

This WILL set both ID's to the same height and the height WILL be equal to the highest. That is what you want, isn't it?

--EDIT--

I would throw away the array if I were you. Just have the 2 DIV's each with a unique ID and make them equally tall based upon that.

- Molle

Answer (score 8):

If you have the DOM document, you can try the below code:

```
let divElement = document.getElementById('divId');
let height = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(divElement).height;
```

'height' will have the exact height of the element with 'divId' once it is computed.

Comment: this gives not exactly the number of height. only "xx%" or "auto". is there another way?