# Vertically align a text inside a inline-block spine with parent container height in percentage

Tags: html, css, center, vertical-alignment

I am struggling to vertically align text iside a `display: inline-block` span.

This `span` is inside a container which has a height set as percentage of its wrapping container:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class ="header">
        <span>test</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

and css:

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    max-height: 1440px;
    max-width: 1920px;
}

.wrap {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 1920px;
    min-width: 1024px;
    max-height: 1440px;
    min-height: 768px;
    background: green;
}

.header {
   background: yellow;
   height: 4.44%;
}

.header span {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height:100%;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: orange;
}
```

and here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2doa8zwa/4/)

I also tried `display:table;` and `display:table-cell;` combo but that didn't work.

Edited:

I also got a question: why line-height:100% doesn't work?

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flexbox can do that.

```
.header span {
  display: -webkit-inline-box;
  display: -webkit-inline-flex;
  display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  background: orange;
}
```

```css
html, body {
    height:100%;
 max-height: 1440px;
 max-width: 1920px;
}

.wrap {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 1920px;
    min-width: 1024px;
    max-height: 1440px;
    min-height: 768px;
    background: green;
}

.header {
   background: yellow;
   height: 4.44%;
}

.header span {
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  background: orange;
}

.mainbody {
  background: red;
  height: 80%;
}

.footer {
  background: blue;
  height:10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
<div class ="header">
<span>test</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Should do...IE10 support flexbox (prefixed I think).

Comment: what would the prefixes be? I found `display: -ms-flexbox;` and `-webkit-flex: 1;`, can you please add them to jsfiddle for me, not sure how to use it?

Answer (score 1):

*>> I also got a question: why line-height:100% doesn't work?*

line-height in percentage is relative to the font-size of the element. Refer [this](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/PR-CSS2-20110412/visudet.html#propdef-line-height).

So, if you want the height and line-height of '.header span' to be the same, you can get the [computed height in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60230586/4745549) and then set it for line-height:

```
let divElement = document.getElementById('divId');
let height = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(divElement).height;
divElement.style.lineHeight = height;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `line-height`

**CSS**

```
.header span {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height:2.2em;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/2doa8zwa/3/)

Comment: I tried this in my code, when the header is scaling down text is no longer aligned in center. also span is not 100% of height of parent div, unless I set height 100% again